# How to solve An unhandled win32 exception occurred in ssms.exe?

Tags: sql-server

Getting **SSMS - SQL Server Management has stopped working** error and after clicking the debug button getting **An unhandled win32 exception occurred in ssms.exe** when I open the SQL Server Management Studio.

Googled and tried This (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24b356ad-59ef-446f-aa8b-df6b55fa78bb/an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred?forum=Vsexpressinstall) one, but no luck.

Note: Today my windows 10 got some update while switch on the PC, after that only this error has occurred. SQL version: SQL Sever Express 2008 R2.

How to resolve this problem?. Pls Advise.

Thanks,

Kavin.S

Comment: You reinstall it.

Comment: After 3 or 4 days, I open the SSMS and its working fine. Its automatically solved i dont know how its happened.